# Using SQL Server trying find results based upon results of another search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I apologise if I am not very clear in my query, I am very new to SQL.

I am using the same table to find two sets of results.

The first query returns results work that have use a specific Job plan (9241,9242,9521, 9522).

```
WHERE
    JPNUM in ('009241','009242','009522','009521')
    AND STATUS NOT LIKE 'CLOSED%'
    AND STATUS NOT LIKE 'CANCELLED%'
```

The second query returns results that have either the Job plan listed above or have a value in a field called orgigrecordid. I may not even need the a.JPNUM part of the query.

```
WHERE
    a.STATUS NOT LIKE 'CLOSED%' 
    AND a.STATUS NOT LIKE 'Cancelled%'
    AND a.JPNUM IN ('009241', '009242', '009522', '009521') 
     OR (a.ORIGRECORDID NOT LIKE 'null%'))
```

Within the results is a column called `ASSETNUM` which is what I will have to use to produce the results I want.

Now for my question: how do I write the code so in the second query I only return rows that have an `ASSETNUM` that appears in the first query?

I hope I have explained myself well enough.

Comment: Without actual sample data, and expected results, we can only guess. Perhaps `INTERSECT`?

Comment: take a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: A CTE isn't a keyword, @mostafa8026 .

Comment: I mean `with`, anyway corrected @Larnu

Comment: `WITH` doesn't just precede a CTE though, @mostafa8026 . `WITH` is a keyword, yes, but it's not the solution, as it can be used in syntaxes like `FROM Object Name}WITH ({Query Hint})` or `CREATE TABLE {Table Name} (...) WITH {Table Options}`.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say, but that `OR` looks wrong. `OR` has lower precedence than `AND`, so `cond1 AND cond2 OR cond3` is the same as `(cond1 AND cond2) OR cond3` and **not the same** as `cond1 AND (cond2 OR cond3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using sub query in your second query. You can add a where condition something like -

```sql
secondquery_assetNumber in (select assetnumber from tablename  WHERE
    JPNUM in ('009241','009242','009522','009521')
    AND STATUS NOT LIKE 'CLOSED%'
    AND STATUS NOT LIKE 'CANCELLED%')
```